# Why is PHPUnit in CakePHP stuck at older version?

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, version

I'm running CakePHP via XAMPP on Ubuntu with PHPUnit 3.6, and I want to upgrade to PHPUnit 3.7. I ran the pear uninstall/install and running `phpunit --version` reports `PHPUnit 3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.`.

However, it now reports as v. 3.7.28 in CLI. However, the browser says version 3.6.

Comment: XAMPP for the browser is likely pointing to the older version of PHPUnit.  Check to ensure you do not have both still installed.

Comment: That may be the case. In fact, when running `phpunit --version` as sudo, it reports "3.7.28", but as a regular user, it reports "3.6".

Comment: try both with the 'which' command (which phpunit) to see where they are getting executed from.

Comment: I already tried that, which produced the 2 different versions.